# Flags with deferred use

Tags: design, design-patterns

Let's say I have a system. In this system I have a number of operations I can do, but all of these operations have to happen as a batch at a certain time, while calls to activate *and* deactivate these operations can come in at any time. No matter how many times the `doOperation1()` method/function is called the operation is done only once in the batch. To implement this, I could use flags like `doOperation1` and `doOperation2` but this seems like it would become difficult to maintain. Is there a design pattern, or something similar, that addresses this situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to look at the [Visitor Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern). It allows you to decouple operations from the objects they work on.  If you extend this pattern, to place those operations into a queue, and then process the queue as a batch, this may work.

Comment: Thanks chris, I'll look into it! I'd vote up if I could.

Answer (score 0):

```
class A {
    void foo() { ... }
}

class DoFooOnce {
    bool activated = false;

    void activateFoo (A obj) {
        if (!activated) {
            activated = true;
            obj.foo();
        }
  }
}


main () {
    A obj1;
    B obj2;
    C obj3;

    DoFooOnce guard;

    guard.activateFoo(obj1);
    guard.activateFoo(obj2);
    guard.activateFoo(obj3);
}
```

Comment: The problem with this implementation is that it will quickly become unmanageable. Imagine having a dozen of these; it would [smell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell) awful and it implies the need for a more interesting approach. This also happens to be the way I solved this problem in my code.

Comment: FWIW, if you have a language with strong template capabilities (e.g. C++), only one such class would need to be created that could handle various object types with various methods.